# How do I get multiple images into GrADS meta file with out doing them one by one

Tags: netcdf, grads

I am working in GrADS to produce plots for a model run (netcdf file) and am very new to this program.  I am trying to find out how to send multiple images to the metadata (all images from animation) without having to do them one at a time.

Another alternative would be to slow the animation on the screen down.

Answer (score -1):

My advice would be to stop using GrADS and switch to Python. I can recommend using the [Iris library](http://scitools.org.uk/iris/docs/latest/gallery.html).